# Reference request: homomorphisms of $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)}$-modules

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

For a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ one can construct $\hat{\mathfrak g}$-modules at level $k$ by taking induced representations from $\mathfrak g$-modules, and then quotienting by the maximal submodule.

I would like a reference/resource which ideally describes all the homomorphisms between irreducible $\hat{\mathfrak g}$-modules, for the case of $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, ideally at arbitrary level $k$.

I am aware of *Lectures on Representation Theory and Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equations* by P. Etingof et al, but I was hoping there might be an alternative resource.